# What "Querying objectives" in CCDH certification specifically mean?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I am planning for CCDH certification. Can anyone help me with the below requirement? Is it like we have to write MR code similar to any of HiveQL like select,join etc? or is it something else?

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/training/certification/ccdh/prep.html

> 4. Querying Objectives
>
>    - Write a MapReduce job to implement a HiveQL statement.
>    - Write a MapReduce job to query data stored in HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Per [this cloudera forum thread](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/General-Questions-Training/CCDH-410-Developer-certification/m-p/14640/highlight/true#M134):

> > please explain what is really expected in part four. Are we really expected to write an entire job ? I can't imagine that, can you clarify this point ? And how difficult are the queries in HiveQL ? Do we have to know subtle select clause ?
>
> In part 4: you are expected to read an entire job (driver, mapper, reducer) and dissect it and be able to understand what the code is doing or not doing. It's basically a dissection exercise: given the following code, what is the outcome. Queries in HiveQL are not difficult if you know HiveQL or SQL which are not difficult.

I can't guarantee it's true, but that's a post by a Cloudera employee (a bit dated though - it's from 2014-02).

Comment: Thanks Nickolay for the update. "Write a MapReduce job to implement a HiveQL statement." is misleading....i thought we have to write some map reduce code which is equal to hiveql statement like select or join